# Picker example gives a TypeError

Tags: javascript, react-native, picker

I copy pasted a `Picker` example from the manual but I constantly get the following error:

> TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
>
> This error is located at:
>       in PickerAndroid (at Picker.js:158)
>       in Picker (at NewNotification.js:32)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:60)
>       in View (at KeyboardAvoidingView.js:196)
>       in KeyboardAvoidingView (at NewNotification.js:23)
>       in NewNotification (at SceneView.js:9)
>       in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.js:478)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:60)
>       in View (at StackViewLayout.js:477)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:60)
>       in View (at StackViewLayout.js:476)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:60)
>       in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:154)
>       in AnimatedComponent (at screens.js:51)
>       in Screen (at StackViewCard.js:42)
>       in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.js:26)
>       in Container (at StackViewLayout.js:507)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:60)
>       in View (at screens.js:76)
>       in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.js:401)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:60)
>       in View (at StackViewLayout.js:400)
>       in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
>       in withOrientation (at StackView.js:49)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:60)
>       in View (at Transitioner.js:141)
>       in Transitioner (at StackView.js:19)
>       in StackView (at createNavigator.js:57)
>       in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:11)
>       in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
>       in NavigationContainer (at App.js:23)
>       in App (at registerRootComponent.js:35)
>       in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:34)
>       in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:33)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:60)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:60)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:32)

My code looks like this:

```
state = {
   location: 'a'
}
render(){
    return(
 <Picker
   selectedValue={this.state.location}
   style={styles.picker}>
   onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({location: itemValue})}>
     <Picker.Item label="a" value="a" />
     <Picker.Item label="b" value="b" />
     <Picker.Item label="c" value="c" />
     <Picker.Item label="d" value="d" />
  </Picker>
```

)}

More information:

```
"expo": "^30.0.1",
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-navigation": "^2.18.1"
```

Comment: you seem to have a typo at `style={styles.picker}>` should be `style={styles.picker}`

Comment: Spot on. I didn't notice the '>' As the error didn't refer to that. Many Thanks Please post it as a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Typo in your code at

```
style={styles.picker}>
```

it should be

```
style={styles.picker}
```